# Eclipse Syntax Coloring File

Tags: eclipse, file, syntax-highlighting

After setting up the Java syntax highlighting for my workspace, I want to backup this file to, lets say, give it to my friends.

Can you tell me in which file Eclipse stores these coloring values?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**SECOND ANSWER (also in comments below)**

Sharing Java color syntax setting is possible by working with various Eclipse preference files. See: http://srand2.blogspot.com/2009/08/eclipse-color-themes.html .

Specifically:

- [workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
- [workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

Also, for future readers, [@jonas-groger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488265/jonas-groger) added comment below regarding http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ as another option.

**FIRST ANSWER (didn't address color syntax)**

Using Eclipse Helios (older versions of Eclipse are similiar):

- Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter
- Select your profile
- Edit
- Export...

This generates an XML file of all your Java formatting settings that can be easily shared/imported.

Comment: Is this also exporting syntax coloring which is set up in Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring?

Comment: ah. No, only formatting. I don't think there is an easy option for sharing color syntax. It is possible by working with  various Eclipse preferences files manually though. See: http://srand2.blogspot.com/2009/08/eclipse-color-themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simply `import/export` would not be enough, so you may need a list of `.pref` files where the syntax coloring settings are stored. What I have here is not complete and I just list what I use and I hope it helps.

(I process `.java`, `.jsp`, `.xml`, `js` and `.properties` files.)

**You can find them by searching `.pref` files in your workspace, and open each one to see which contains color code.** Remember to adjust your searching options to look into subfolders.

```
org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.ant.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqleditor.prefs
org.eclipse.debug.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.php.ui.prefs
com.adobe.flexide.mxml.core.prefs
org.python.pydev.prefs
com.adobe.flexide.as.core.prefs
com.adobe.flexide.css.core.prefs
org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.prefs
org.epic.perleditor.prefs
org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs
```

You may copy them when you finish adjusting your syntax coloring settings. When needed, search `.pref` again to get access to their locations, and **restore your settings by copying the lines with color code, in order to avoid unpredictable side effect.** As I can see this is the only way, inconvenient buy effective.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, try out the [Eclipse Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) plugin. It's easier.

See some [themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=downloads&q=). I prefer bright ones but there are dark ones also.

After you install the plugin, go to `Windows > Preferences` and there `General > Appearance > Color Themes` and pick one.

If you want to use the Intellij IDEA Theme, you must [download the xml](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=935) for it (not the .epf) and import it with the dialog.

[image]

(I'm *not* a developer of this plugin)

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is no longer active, see https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/273...

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an `.epf` file (Eclipse preference file) with the preferences which are otherwise stored in the  `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.jdt.prefs` file.

Later, you can import the `.epf` file via "File > Import > General > Preferences".

Here is an example `.epf` file (make sure to include the `file_export_version=3.0` line, the import will not work otherwise!):

```ini
file_export_version=3.0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/java_multi_line_comment=128,128,128
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/java_single_line_comment=128,128,128
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/java_string=255,0,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.abstractMethodInvocation.color=0,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.abstractMethodInvocation.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.abstractMethodInvocation.italic=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.abstractMethodInvocation.underline=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.field.color=0,0,255
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.inheritedField.color=0,0,255
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.inheritedField.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.inheritedField.italic=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.inheritedMethodInvocation.color=0,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.inheritedMethodInvocation.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.inheritedMethodInvocation.italic=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.localVariable.color=255,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.localVariableDeclaration.bold=false
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.localVariableDeclaration.color=255,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.localVariableDeclaration.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.method.color=0,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.method.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.number.color=128,0,64
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.number.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.parameterVariable.bold=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.parameterVariable.color=255,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.parameterVariable.enabled=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticField.bold=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticField.color=0,0,255
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticField.italic=false
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticFinalField.color=0,0,255
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticFinalField.italic=false
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticMethodInvocation.bold=true
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticMethodInvocation.color=0,128,0
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/semanticHighlighting.staticMethodInvocation.italic=false
```