# Eclipse for Android, lost code completion feature

Tags: eclipse, code-completion

I wanted to transfer my Syntax coloring settings from my Eclipse EE to my Eclipse for Android, so I did what is told in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818197/eclipse-syntax-coloring-file). The problem is that, even if my syntax coloring did apply correctly, I lost all my code completion and proposals (and, conveniently enough, I didn't make a backup)! If I press ctrl + space, I get a No default proposals message. Always.

I wouldn't like to have to install the whole IDE again, so if someone could provide a solution to this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced` lists the default content assist proposals. Check that some proposals are actually enabled.